# javascript element of array stays unchangeable, even after change value

Tags: javascript, html

My problem is this:

Suppose this class, it's an example of my true code:

```js
class TileMap {
    constructor ( w, h ) {
        this.tiles = [];

        // init the matrix
        for (var i = 0; i < h; i++) {
            var a = [];
            for (var j = 0; j < w; j++) {
                a.push(0);
            }
            this.tiles[i] = a;
        }
    }

    setTile (x, y, tile) {
        this.tiles[y][x] = tile;
    }

    doSomething () {
        this.setTile(0, 0, 1);
        this.setTile(0, 1, 2);
    }
}

// What's happening is when I use like this:
var player = {};
player.map = new TileMap(32, 90, 90);

player.map.doSomething();
console.log("before Tile[0][0] = " + player.map.tiles[0][0]);

player.map.setTile(0, 0, 3);
console.log("after Tile[0][0] = " + player.map.tiles[0][0]);
```

Shows me the follow output:

```
before Tile[0][0] = 1
after Tile[0][0] = 1
```

The matrix are modified but turn back to before values.
What should I do? (NOTE I'm not familiar with javascript but with language like C++)

Comment: I get `after Tile[0][0] = 3` Could you show your actual code?

Comment: Works for me too

Comment: Yes, I do this before, But I have function in the class TileMap that modifies the array directly and I get the same result: modifies and turn back to original.

Comment: if I run player.map.tiles[0][0] works perfectly, but I don't understand why in the class it not works

Comment: I edit your question and added a snippet but it works there.

Comment: wait, could it be that you don't log just some primitive value that you overwrite, but instead an object that you're mutating? And what do you mean by `why in the class it not works`. How does it not work in the class? What do you expect, what do you get?

Comment: the shared code is working for me too.                         https://jsfiddle.net/55whppo6/  .. Share the function that is modifying the array in class.

Comment: Please delete this question if it was an issue you could solve by looking at the code yourself

Comment: I cannot delete the question, here shows me a message that is impossible because many people efforts etc. Sorry for this.
The erro was because of logical error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand what is wrong. I added to your code the player object.

```js
class TileMap{
  constructor ( w, h ){
    this.tiles = [];
    //init the matrix
    for (var i = 0; i < h; i++)
    {
      var a = [];
      for (var j = 0; j < w; j++)
        a.push(0);
      this.tiles[i] = a;
    }
  }

  setTile (x, y, tile){
    this.tiles[y][x] = tile;
  }

  doSomething (){
    this.setTile(0,0, 1);
    this.setTile(0,1, 2);
  }
}

//What's happening is when I use like this:
var player = {};
player.map = new TileMap(32,90,90);
player.map.doSomething();
console.log("before Tile[0][0] = "+player.map.tiles[0][0]);
player.map.setTile(0,0, 3);
console.log("after Tile[0][0] = "+player.map.tiles[0][0]);
```

Comment: SOrry man, I don't can share the full source, that was a simple example and should works perfectly. I will review my code, should be something that I'm not seeing... but thank you

Comment: Oh man, many thank you! With your little snappet I was motivated to review the entire code and now works like a charm hehehe

Comment: @samleo No problem!